# what is the best way to display long text in xaml for windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, longtext

In my project .I need to display loog texts,it is some kind of book app project .i know how to read a txt file in c# but it doesn't look efficient to me there should be more easy and customable ways. do you know any other way to display long texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control.

[Here's the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431811%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for using it with a string.

XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" />
```

C#:

```
string LongText = "blablabla";
webBrowser.NavigateToString(LongText);
```

Comment: i want to ask a question .when i read text into a string would i be able to change font with webbrowser control,i mean your string is longtext would you be able to change font size color etc from webrowser element

Comment: You can add a style with CSS: `<style>body{font-size:20px;color:#ccc}</style>`